# Javascript and HTML5 Canvas sprite

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, sprite

i was following a tutorial about sprites on:
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/
I have a sprite working now but i like the sprite to have more then one animation. Those animation should depend on a certain state this sprite should have.

What i like to do is creating the paratroopers in the old Apple game airborne. For an example see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYujWCNUuNw
You see those troopers drop out of a chopper. When they are on the ground they stan idle for a while and then they start walking every now and then.

Here i my sprite method:

```
function sprite(options) {
var that = {},
frameIndex = 0,
tickCount = 0, ticksPerFrame = options.ticksPerFrame || 0, numberOfFrames = options.numberOfFrames || 1;
that.x = options.x, that.y = options.y,
that.context = options.context;
that.width = options.width;
that.height = options.height;
that.image = options.image;

that.update = function() {
    tickCount += 1;

    if (tickCount > ticksPerFrame) {

        tickCount = 0;

        // If the current frame index is in range
        if (frameIndex < numberOfFrames - 1) {
            // Go to the next frame
            frameIndex += 1;
        } else {
            frameIndex = 0;
        }
    }
};

that.render = function() {
    // Draw the animation
    that.context.drawImage(that.image,
        frameIndex * that.width / numberOfFrames,
        0,
        that.width / numberOfFrames,
        that.height, that.x,
        that.y,
        that.width / numberOfFrames,
        that.height);
};
return that;
}
```

How can i get this sprite to have those extra animation options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an offset value which points to each regions:

```
var offsets = [0, animation2x, animation3x, ...];
```

Then when you change the type of animation using an integer value representing the index of your offset array you can do:

```
var animation = 1;

hat.context.drawImage(that.image,
    offsets[animation] + frameIndex * that.width / numberOfFrames,
    ....
```

You may need or want to add other information to the offset which might as well be an object containing number of frames, sizes and so forth.

A pseudo example could look like this:

```
var offsets = [{offset:0, frames:12, w:100, h:100},
               {offset:1200, frames:7, w: 90, h:100},
               ...];
...

var offset = offsets[animation];

hat.context.drawImage(that.image,
    offset.offset + frameIndex * offset.w / offset.frames,
    ....

if (frameIndex > offset.frames) ...
```

Optionally you just use different images for each animation and use the same approach but instead store objects with pointer to the image you want to use.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response. Thanks Ken this is very usefull.